# XMPPFramework - How to add custom properties to XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I have developed a chat application using XMPPFramework, but i'm facing a problem and now i'm stuck. I use NSFetchedResultsController to show the list of users saved on my chat, but now i have to show extra informations such as gender and placeId.
   I tried the follow:

Add the properties in XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject.h and then:

```
- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [self.xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[presence from]
                                                         xmppStream:self.xmppStream
                                               managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

user.venueId = [presence attributeStringValueForName:@"KEY_VENUEID"];
user.gender = [presence attributeStringValueForName:@"KEY_GENDER"];

NSError *error = nil;
[[self managedObjectContext_roster] save:&error];
}
```

But when I try to use these properties, the app crashes (unrecognized selector). Is it possible to add custom properties to XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject? What am I doing wrong? I saw a lot of tutorials in internet and followed the demo code of XMPPFramework, but didn't find anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject.h is autogenerated file from CoreData model. You should add properties to model and then regenerate headers.

Comment: Can u brief on how to add properties to autogenerated file (XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject) from coredata and regenerate headers. @vitalyster